# A 4 x 4 Magic Square with Pairwise Relatively Prime Entries

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle, magic-square

Find a 4 x 4 magic square of positive integers such that any two of its entries are pairwise different and relatively prime, i.e., have no common divisor greater than 1.

What is the least that the largest number in such a square can be?

Comment: What is “pairwise different”?

Comment: @ArvasuKulkarni: Any two entries are different. They are also relatively prime, that is, they do not have a common divisor greater than 1.

Comment: Was this puzzle of your own creation?

Comment: @Brandon_J: An oldie twisted.

Comment: Wow, that's the **best** puzzle I ever encountered here (and I've been a lurker for more than a year, I think). A question about the definition: can the square contain a 1, i. e. is 1 considered a coprime to any other natural number or not? It commonly is, but not always.

Comment: Also, I am assuming the sums of the two main diagonals must also equal the sum of each row and column, correct? Ah, and the generalization of the problem to $n\times n$ squares is likely publishable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is optimal (unless I've missed a trick):

> ```
>   1 13 47 53
>  29 59  7 19
>  41 11 37 25
>  43 31 23 17
> ```

Which has

> a maximal value of 59 (and a sum of 114)
>
>  Note: all values are prime except for 1 and the composite number 25

I also found these two with the same maximum value:

> ```
>   1 17 37 59
>  53 29 23  9
>  47 19 43  5
>  13 49 11 41
> ```
>
> ...using primes, 1, 9 and 49 (with a sum of 114);
>  and
>
> ```
>   1 29 47 49
>  43 41 37  5
>  59 17 31 19
>  23 39 11 53
> ```
>
> ...using primes, 1, 39 and 49 (with a sum of 126)

---

First I found these two:

> ```
>  1 11 41 61
> 47 31 17 19
> 43 13 53  5
> 23 59  3 29
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>  1 13 47 53
> 29 59  7 19
> 61 31 17  5
> 23 11 43 37
> ```
>
> both of which have a maximal value of 61 (and a sum of 114)

For these I restricted myself to fifteen odd primes less than 73 and added the number one as the sixteenth value. These two have the smallest maximal value given this additional constraint.

Comment: http://www.markfarrar.co.uk/msq4x4cm.htm does not like your solution, but I can't find the error.

Comment: The diagonals work, but not whatever else this considers when deciding if it is "perfect" - looking at the results when you give a magic total it seems to want squares and offset 2-by-1s or 1-by-2s and non-main diagonals.

Comment: Oh dang. Can I give you a +47 or so for finding this answer?

Comment: Just found better :p

Answer (score 3):

I've got a solution:

> and I admit I found it [online](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeMagicSquare.html).

Here it is:

> [image: Magic Square]

The largest number in it is

> 73

Comment: Maybe we can make a smaller one by using 1 as one of our numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure. I feel like I found a pretty reliable source @JonathanAllan

Comment: I am not doubting Mathworld as a source, but did A. W. Johnson, Jr allow 1 or not?

Comment: @JonathanAllan ah, I see what you mean. Does the OP allow the number one? I guess I should ask.

Comment: 1 is co-prime to all other integers. Note that I asked if we are only allowed positive integers because the same is true of -1.

Comment: @JonathanAllan, while 1 is usually considered a *coprime* to any natural number, it is not regarded a *prime* on its own, in the modern sense (although Goldbach did condsider 1 a prime). So it is almost certain that Johnson, assuming he was a contemporary of Dewdney, did not admit 1 into the square of prime numbers.

Comment: @kkm exactly (1 is not now considered a prime or, indeed, a composite) - the page linked states "although the number 1 is sometimes allowed in such squares" it does not state whether that square admits 1 or not (I suspected not). It also does not say if it is the square uses the smallest primes possible (I think I'll check that tonight :)), just that it was "found by ...".

Comment: @kkm there are two (up to symmetry) prime-only ones with 71 as maximum: `(13, 23, 37, 59), (29, 31, 19, 53), (47, 11, 71, 3), (43, 67, 5, 17)` and `(19, 29, 37, 53), (71, 17, 47, 3), (41, 31, 43, 23), (7, 61, 11, 59)` (and none using only lower primes).

Comment: @JonathanAllan, interesting, thanks! Did you computer-check it, or used another proof technique? It seems to me that both this prime-only and the OP problems reduce quickly to the set packing problem, which is a well-known NP-complete one. I do not yet understand if it's inevitable, tho. (As a side note, I would not call 1 a composite number, even though a non-prime.)

Comment: @kkm I wrote code to check for solutions and I utilised sets to whittle down possibilities for each set of 16 numbers being tried (so brute-force without the state-space explosion of naive checking). RE side-note: 1 is not a composite number (which is exactly what I stated above, but maybe not clearly). -- BTW this may get moved to a chat room, since comments are not meant for extended discussion (for general puzzling chat visit The Spinx's Lair at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524).

Answer (score 1):

The following magic square

> ```
>  11  1 53 37
>   7 47 29 19
>  71 23  3  5
>  13 31 17 41
> ```

has magic constant

> 102

and largest number

> 71